# How can I get user id from session in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

How can I get the user id from session in javascript?

I was using this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var sessionUserId = '<?php $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>';
    alert (sessionUserId);
});
```

Comment: You forgot to actually echo the value: `<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>`. But why do you need to put user ID into the JS, dare I ask?

Comment: If you need a session user id on the client, something has already gone wrong.

Comment: I was thinking differently. But is there any restrictions on using session value in JS?Sorry I am new..

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? For me you don't need the user id, the server know who is authenticated, you don't have to use it anywhere in js, just send your requests to the server and it will fill the user id

Comment: It's just generally not a great idea to expose IDs to the client side if you don't have to. I could understand maybe providing the user's _name_, so you could display it, but I'm not really sure why the JS code would need to know the ID? What are you planning to use it for?

Comment: I wanted to send the user id to firebase through javascript.

Comment: Ok, well that does make a bit more sense. Just bear in mind that a malicious user could, if they wished, mess with this and cause a different user ID to be sent to firebase...and maybe that could cause some sort of security breach. If that is crucial, you might be better to communicate with firebase from the PHP side. It probably depends really on whether you have any access rules around the data which rely on knowing which user the data is associated with.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your page with php extension, create an input with the value of your user id and style none to don´t display on page.

```
<input id="userId" value="<?php $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>" style="display:none">
```

When page is load call the value of your input with jQuery and id.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   alert( $('#userId').val() );
   console.log('done');
});
```